# 415 Unsupported Media Type Error while posting data to Spring MVC Rest Controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, postman

I am working with simple Spring MVC REST CURD operations.
I am able to access `GET` and `DELETE` methods. 
But, `POST` & `PUT` are not working.

While posting data to api url, the postman showing `415 Unsupported Media Type Error`

The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Guys, please help to solve this problem

I am just trying out with the code from git

### CustomerController.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.vodafone.crud.dto.CustomerDto;
import com.vodafone.crud.model.Customer;
import com.vodafone.crud.model.Status;
import com.vodafone.crud.service.DataServices;


/**
* @author Geeth
*
*/
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
DataServices dataServices;

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerController.class);

/**
 * Use to add a new customer to database.
 * 
 * @param dto
 *            Customer data transfer object
 * @return Whether success of the operation
 *, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Status addCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto dto) {
    logger.debug("Delegating to service to return Added Customer");
    try {



        dataServices.addEntity(dto);
        logger.debug("Customer added Successfully !");
        return new Status(1, "Customer added Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Customer wasn't added !");
        return new Status(0, e.toString());
    }

}

/**
 * Use to update an existing customer to database.
 * 
 * @param dto
 *            Customer data transfer object
 * @return Whether success of the operation
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Status updateCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto dto) {
    logger.debug("Delegating to service to return updated Customer");
    try {
        dataServices.updateEntity(dto);
        return new Status(1, "Customer updated Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Customer wasn't updated !");
        return new Status(0, e.toString());
    }

}

/**
 * Use to retrieve an exiting customer
 * 
 * @param id
 *            Unique identifier of the particular customer.
 * @return Fetched customer
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody CustomerDto getCustomer(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    logger.debug("Delegating to service to return Customer " + id);
    CustomerDto dto = null;
    try {
        dto = dataServices.getEntityById(id);

    } catch (Exception exe) {
        logger.debug("Customer wasn't fetched " + id);
        logger.error(exe.getMessage());
    }
    return dto;
}

/**
 * Use to retrieve all existing customers
 * 
 * @return List of fetched customers
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<CustomerDto> getCustomers() {
    logger.debug("Delegating to service to return all Customers");
    List<CustomerDto> customerList = null;
    try {
        customerList = dataServices.getEntityList();

    } catch (Exception exe) {
        logger.debug("Customers fetching was failed");
        logger.error(exe.getMessage());
    }

    return customerList;
}

/**
 * Use to delete an existing customer
 * 
 * @param id
 *            Unique identifier of the particular customer.
 * @return Whether success of the operation
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Status deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    logger.debug("Delegating to service to delete Customer" + id);
    try {
        dataServices.deleteEntity(id);
        return new Status(1, "Customer deleted Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception exe) {
        logger.debug("Customer wasn't deleted " + id);
        return new Status(0, exe.toString());
    }

}
}
```

Customer.java(Model/Entity Class):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phoneNumber;


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}


public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}


public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

}
```

### POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>vodafone.crud</groupId>
<artifactId>Vodafone</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <context.path>SpringRestCrud</context.path>
</properties>

   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: And where is the code? We aren't wizards here.

Comment: did you set the `Content-type` header?

Comment: Yes, i have set "Accept" too...

Comment: Pls check, i have updated my post with code...

Comment: 1. Set Content-type : application/json , 2. Validate your request json [here](http://pro.jsonlint.com/). If it still doesnt work, post the error stacktrace mentioning "which" endpoint causes that error.

Comment: I recently had this error (415) and the problem was in the DTO class (it had 2 conflicting setter). So you may want to check on that side if you have this error.